# JMeter BeanShell Assertion Custom Output Messages

Tags: jmeter

I was asked to enhance my assertions to provide some better log messaging within my JMeter test plan that tests APIs using basic CRUD methodology. The test plan is being checked into Jenkins and being run automatically. When something goes wrong, the level of messaging is not adequate for the support team.

Within the first thread group, I have an HTTP Request to create a new record within the database based on the payload being passed in. Under this request, I have a BeanShell Assertion as follows:

```
if (ResponseCode.equals("200") == true) 
{ 
    SampleResult.setResponseOK();  
}
```

I'm now trying to enhance this to account for 409, and 500 responses.

I've attempted the, but it does not seem to work:

```
if (ResponseCode.equals("200") == true) 
{ 
    SampleResult.setResponseOK();  
}

else if (ResponseCode.equals("409") == true) 
{ 
    FailureMessage = "Creation of a new CAE record failed: Attempting to create a duplicate record.";
}

else (ResponseCode.equals("500") == true) 
{ 
   FailureMessage = "Creation of a new CAE record failed: Unable to connect to server";
}
```

Additionally, if the ResponseCode is not 200, then I need to drop out of the entire thread group and go to the next thread group.

I've read several questions on this site, as well as *[How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](http://azemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell?utm_source=BM&utm_medium=BM_blog&utm_campaign=JMeter_Assertions_blog)* and *[How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)*, but I'm still confused. Not being a developer and still new to JMeter, I'm in need of guidance.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting 'Stop Thread' in the Thread Group would help you to stop the thread group in case of any error - assuming you have other thread groups to execute consecutively. if not, the test will stop.

In the beanshell assetion include

```
else if (ResponseCode.equals("409") == true) 
{ 
   Failure = true;
    FailureMessage = "Creation of a new CAE record failed: Attempting to create a duplicate record.";
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you suggesting I do this within the BeanShell Assertion? 



    if (ResponseCode.equals("200") == true)  
    { 
 SampleResult.setResponseOK(); 
    }  
    else if (Failure == true)  
    {  
 FailureMessage = "Creation of a new CAE record failed: " + SampleResult.setResponseOK() + " code was received." + "\n"; 
    }

Comment: @David, check the updated answer. Just add 'Failure=true;' as well before the failuremessage.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That worked. Appreciate the help!